# SwiftUI: searchable weird push animation?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have the following code:

```
enum ContentViewRouter {
    case details
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(value: ContentViewRouter.details) {
                    Text("Push")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ContentViewRouter.self) { destiantion in
                switch destiantion {
                case .details:
                    DetailsView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("TEST")
        }
    }
    
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @State var query = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section("TEST") {
                Text("DETAILS")
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $query)
        .navigationTitle("DETAILS")
        
    }
    
}
```

When pushing the details view it creates this animation:

[image]

I want to get rid of this weird looking animation "glitch":

[image]

How can I get the push animation to come in smooth where the search bar doesn't appear for a split second and then go away? Seems like it's a bug or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you have any luck recently with this glitch animation?

Comment: no, no luck for now. I wish I had a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of that I think because you have `.searchable` which will create search bar and currently conflict with your `.navigationTitle` which both on the top. Maybe the search bar don't know where to put it because of the `.navigationTitle`

**Update:** After doing some research, I see that maybe the behavior maybe wrong in search bar `.automatic`

There are three ways to workaround

1. If you want to keep your search bar then make `NavigationView` to split define navigationTitle and search bar

```swift
struct DetailsView: View {
    @State var query = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section("TEST") {
                    Text("DETAILS")
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $query)
        }
        .navigationTitle("DETAILS")
        
    }
}
```

2. Keep the search bar always appear

```swift
struct DetailsView: View {
    @State var query = ""
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section("TEST") {
                Text("DETAILS")
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $query, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        .navigationTitle("DETAILS")
    }
}
```

3. If you want to completely remove search bar

```swift
struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @State var query = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section("TEST") {
                Text("DETAILS")
            }
        }
        //.searchable(text: $query) // remove this
        .navigationTitle("DETAILS")
        
    }   
}
```

Comment: I do need to keep searchable. Option 1 approach puts an additional navigation bar in the view. I don't want that.

Comment: Dear @zumzum, I just figure one more solution make searchBar always appear. If there is any other methods I willupdate

Comment: yes, `.always` does remove the animation. Problem is, I lose the ability to put the searcher on the top right when on iPad... It seems to be like this is a SwiftUI bug. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution by toggling the navigation bar visibility:

```
struct DetailsView: View {

    @State var query : String = ""
    @State private var toolbarVisibility : Visibility = .hidden

    var body: some View {

        Form {
            Section("TEST") {
                Text("DETAILS")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {toolbarVisibility = .automatic}
        .toolbar(toolbarVisibility, for: .navigationBar)
        .searchable(text: $query)
        .navigationTitle("DETAILS")

    }

}
```

---

This worked for me:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @State var query = ""
    @State private var formHasAppeared = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section("TEST") {
                Text("DETAILS")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { formHasAppeared = true }
        .if(formHasAppeared) { view in
            view.searchable(text: $query)
        }
        .navigationTitle("DETAILS")
        
    }
    
}

extension View {
    /// Applies the given transform if the given condition evaluates to `true`.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - condition: The condition to evaluate.
    ///   - transform: The transform to apply to the source `View`.
    /// - Returns: Either the original `View` or the modified `View` if the condition is `true`.
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

The extension came from [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/conditional-view-modifier/)